# emgucv face recognition

Tags: c#, face-recognition, emgucv

can someone please show me an example, or links, about using emgucv to create a face recognition application? I've managed to create a webcam capture and face detection, but having trouble to recognize the face. I have sample images, using EigenObjectRecognizer classs to recgonize. but it looks like a failure, no matter whose face captured, always returns a label. And also, how to knwo the "matching percentage" of an image?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There are some excellent face recognition tutorials available on this site check [the link](http://fewtutorials.bravesites.com/tutorials).

Video tutorials on implementing face recognition can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/user/Mahvish87/videos).

Comment: i think she didn't implement the recognizer part.

Comment: @Napster: In the tutorial section 3b she did include some code snippets, otherwise I have updated the answer with a link to her youtube channel where you can view the video tutorials of the same, and also in the end of the text tutorial page there is a link to download the complete source  code you can have a look at the code there. :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you as the alternative is reading several papers and coding them yourself (Google Scholar is a good resource) but I stumbled across a [Face Recognition Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/FaceRecPro.aspx) (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/FaceRecPro.aspx) on codeproject that does what your attempting with the Eigen classifiers in EMGU. All the source code is available and it is a good article worth reading at the very least,

Cheers

Chris

Comment: I had time to look at the code and write new version that's is easier to train and use. I'm in the process of writing a article for it but in the mean time if you would like a copy let me know where I can send it and I'll email you a copy.